# What causes having to verify daily?

Tags: user-management

I have a user who access SF thru an Ipad but not thru SF1 and he needs to reverify everyday.  Why and how do I correct for him?

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Kerry. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and take our [Tour] to better understand how this forum works, including [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). It would be very helpful to anyone trying to assist you if you told us what you've tried so far and what kind of authentication you have for log in (SSO?) along with anything the user has tried on their end to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this will be because he is connecting to Wi-Fi and 3G/4G from different places, which is causing his IP address to change.

You can whitelist his IP address in the security settings, however if it is changing daily then you are pretty stuck here to be honest, well as far as I am aware.

Comment: He could also be clearing his browser's cache of cookies, etc., whenever he closes his device.

Comment: That won't really make any difference as far as I am aware... Salesforce stores IP addresses if it doesn't recognise them and that will be server side not client side.

Comment: Each device usually needs a token stored on it before you can log-in from it.